# What is disadvantage of using CART in regression problems?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

Why is CART hardly used for regression?

Is there any significant reason for its unpopularity in regression techniques?

Comment: Why do you say that it is hardly used for regression?

Comment: Because i could see many data scientist opts for lasso, ridge, elasticnet or advanced boosting model for most of the problems while CART is predominantly preferred for classification.. So i just wanna know is there any significant disadvantage of using it in regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression and classification trees are nearly identical in how they function. I'm not aware of any specific downside to *regression* trees specifically. However, trees in general do have the downside of being susceptible to overfitting:

> The main downside of decision trees is that even with the use of pre-pruning, they
>   tend to overfit and provide poor generalization performance. Therefore, in most
>   applications,...ensemble methods...are usually used in place of a single decision tree.

Muller & Guido, *Introduction to Machine Learning with Python*, 2017.